# Minimum hardware and software requirements to run mobile apps built with React Native

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I am looking to source some testing Android and iOS devices for React Native apps. I've looked at the [official docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started), but there isn't a specific section for it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a set of 'minimum requirements' per se. React-native applications should work on most modern smartphones, and even some very old ones.

The caveat I would raise here is that it's more about how the app is written, there are many things you can do inside react-native that will kill performance on older devices, such as avoiding unnecessary UI element frame updates. (This can happen if you are hooking into the state changes non optimally)

I suggest having a look at some common anti-patterns when it comes to RN, a good place to start would be here: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/performance (this page goes over common reasons why apps will be performing slowly.)

Answer (score 0):

For your scenario there is no any official smart devices which are recommended to use to test React Native applications.

You can use any of smart devices of both Android and iOS to test your applications.

**For testing your applications on Android :**

- Android 4.1 (API 16) or newer. ( You can find minSDKVersion from android studio app gradle file)

So you can run your application any smart device on or above Android OS 4.1

**For testing your applications on iOS :**

- iOS 9.0 or newer ( You can find Target min OS version from Deployment Info on XCODE )

So you can run your application any smart device on or above iOS 9.0

**Note :**

- My solution is to find devices with different screen sizes.
- If you are going to test iOS application try to use different screen sizes and different os Apple devices like -> iPhone SE , iPhone 6s , iPhone 8 Plus , iPhone X
- For iPhones try to test both notch devices and normal old devices because you need to avoid notch issues with height and width.
- For Android try to use different android os running devices which have different screen sizes with different brands.
- As example try to use both low end budget and high end flagship models.

***You can find requirements from official git repo [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native#-requirements)***